# Mineflayer bot crashing after listener timeout

Tags: python, node.js

```
from javascript import require, On, Once, AsyncTask, once, off

mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
inventoryViewer = require('mineflayer-web-inventory')
item = require('prismarine-item')


# create bot
BOT_USERNAME = 'Robol'
bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 55337,
    'username': BOT_USERNAME,
    'hideErrors': False,
    'version': '1.18.1'})

inventoryViewer(bot)


@On(bot, 'chat')
def handle(this, sender, message, *args):
    if sender == BOT_USERNAME:
        return

    msg = message.split()

    if message.startswith('.stop'):
        bot.end()
    if message.startswith('.tph'):
        teleport(sender)
    if message.startswith('.dig'):
        dig_down()
    if message.startswith('.drop'):
        if len(msg) > 1:
            drop(msg[1])
        else:
            drop(1)


def blockUnder(playerName):
    if playerName == BOT_USERNAME:
        return bot.blockAt(bot.entity.position.offset(0, -1, 0))
    else:
        return bot.blockAt(bot.players[playerName].entity.position.offset(0, -1, 0))


def teleport(playerName):
    if playerName in bot.players:
        if blockUnder(playerName).displayName == 'Air':
            bot.chat('You have to stand on the ground')
        else:
            bot.chat(f'/tp {playerName}')
    else:
        bot.chat('No entity was found')


def dig_down():
    try:
        while bot.canDigBlock(blockUnder(BOT_USERNAME)):
            bot.dig(blockUnder(BOT_USERNAME))

        bot.chat("Can't dig deeper")
    except Exception:
        bot.chat("Stopped digging")
```

^^^^
This throws:

```
[JSE] C:\Users\BigGay\PycharmProjects\BOT\venv\lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:149
[JSE]       throw new BridgeException(`Attempt to access '${stack.join('.')}' failed.`)
[JSE]             ^
[JSE] 
[JSE] BridgeException [Error]: Attempt to access '' failed. Python didn't respond in time (100000ms), look above for any Python errors. If no errors, the API call hung.
[JSE]     at C:\Users\BigGay\PycharmProjects\BOT\venv\lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:149:13
[JSE]     at waitFor (C:\Users\BigGay\PycharmProjects\BOT\venv\lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:46:26)
[JSE]     at async PyBridge.call (C:\Users\BigGay\PycharmProjects\BOT\venv\lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:148:18)
[JSE] 
[JSE] Node.js v18.12.1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

After sending a message in chat while bot is digging

What is the problem here and how to break from loop like in dig_down() with a chat command

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase timeout value by setting `checkTimeoutInterval` with a larger value:

```js
bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: process.argv[2],
    port: process.argv[3],
    username: username + i,
    password: password,
    checkTimeoutInterval: 60 * 10000 // timeout after 600 seconds.
})
```

References:

- https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/issues/710
- https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/pull/698